# JSP Resources Not Loading in Spring MVC 2.5

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using `id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"` for a Spring MVC project, and
I have some resources which I want to include in my JSP files. The HTML includes some .css/.js/.png and other format files which are located in the "assets" folder. 
Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>title</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is the spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="basepackge" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/WebContent/WEB-INF/assets/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB-INF/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"> <value>.jsp</value></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

As mentioned, I have an assets folder and HTML files which use .js/.css from the asset folder. Both of these are in WEB-INF folder. Now, when I'm including such HTML files in my JSP, the .png/.js/.css files are not loading. Can anyone help?

Comment: Post the code where you are including the static resources?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the mapping.  You have defined the prefix with /WEB-INF/ in your spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml which is correct:

```
<property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB-INF/</value></property>
```

But, you then tell Spring that your assets are in the /WebContent/WEB-INF/assets/ folder:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/WebContent/WEB-INF/assets/" />
```

The combination of these two is telling Spring to resolve any request mappings with /assets/** to {prefix}{location}, which would be /WEB-INF/WebContent/WEB-INF/assets/

Change the location in your assets/** mapping to the following (remove '/WebContent/WEB-INF'):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
```